# Find set difference between two integer intervals

Tags: algorithm

I've recently faced a problem. I had to find set difference between two integer intervals. Interval is determined by two borders - high and low. Where the high point isn't included.

Well I came up with solution, to consider several cases. All of a sudden it's ~12 cases. I listed some of them below. Looks wierd. Is there a simpler solution?

```
        //a[  a) b[  b) 
        // [   )  
        if (a._end <= b._start)
            return Lst(a);

        //a[  b[  a)  b)
        // [   )
        if (a._start < b._start && b._start < a._end &&
            b._start < a._end && a._end < b._end)
            return Lst(Rng(a.Start(), b.Start()));

        //b[  a[  b)  a)
        //         [   )
        if (b._start < a._start && a._start < b._end &&
            a._start < b._end && b._end < a._end)
            return Lst(Rng(b.End(), a.End()));

        //b[  b) a[  a)  
        //        [   )
        if (b._end <= a._start)
            return Lst(a);

        //a[  b[  b)  a)
        // [   )   [   )
        if (a._start < b._start && b._start < a._end &&
            a._start < b._end && b._end < a._end)
            return Lst(
                Rng(a.Start(), b.Start()),
                Rng(b.End(), a.End()));
```

Comment: It looks like you listed everything. 4 cases. What are the other 8?

Comment: I consider empty set, when borders are same and when b contains a: O any,  b[  a[  a)  b), ab[   a)  b), ab[   b)  a), b[  a[  ab), a[  b[  ab), ab[   ab). You are right  constructing result incrementally, reduces it dramatically.

Comment: Is there a difference between `a._start` and `a.Start()`? You seem to be using both.

Comment: no, it just a way to push generic argument in new instance of interval. There is data attached to each border (for example DateTime, or some tuple). So when we produce new interval, we don't lose that information. This data strictly depends on integer value, I mean if a._start == b._start, then attached info is also equal (or it doesn't matter what we peek).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I don't see why you decided to generate such redundant conditions as `... b._start < a._end && b._start < a._end ...`)

Among other things, your code is made more complicated by your attempts to build the entire result within a single return statement. If you could just build the result incrementally in a local variable and then just return that local variable, the code would be greatly simplified.

Relying on standard functions like `min` and `max` instead of embedding the `min/max` logic into your code will also make it much more compact.

Let's say we build the result in the local list variable `result` and append intervals to it by doing `result.append()`.

The difference operation can produce up to two intervals: one to the left of `b`, another to the right of `b`. Let's just calculate them in that order

```
List result;

if (a._start < b._start)
  // Left portion exists
  result.append(Rng(a._start, min(a._end, b_start)));

if (a._end > b._end)
  // Right portion exists
  result.append(Rng(max(a._start, b._end), a._end));
  
return result;
```

I assumed that the intervals are already normalized, i.e. `a._start <= a._end`, but it seems that your code also relies on that assumption.

Comment: The second append has a small mistake: it should be `result.append(Rng(max(a._start, b._end), a._end))`